# how can i selected css :first-child not work in li

Tags: javascript, css

css not work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46gjd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fck9c.png)

i hope the .a class first color will be red , but not work .

```html
<style>
  .a:first-child {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li title="1" class="a">1</li>
    <li title="2" class="a">2</li>
    <li title="3" class="a">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `<li>0</li>` is the first child, but it doesn't have a class of `a`

Comment: but how to select class = a  and first  .

Comment: i hope  <li title="1" class="a">1</li> is red

Comment: I know what you want, but I don't think it's possible with what you have

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` pseudo-class only works when your element is the first child of its parent.

Unfortunately, there's no "elegant" way to do what you try to do, i.e. there's no `:first-of-class` as of yet. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/3930247) for more details.

So, a bit more code but this is probably the most "elegant" way to do it currently:

```html
<style>
  /* Color all "a" class elements with red */
  .a {
    color: red;
  }
  
  /* Make all "a" class elements with default color, except for the first one */
  .a ~ .a {
    color: inherit;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li title="1" class="a">1</li>
    <li title="2" class="a">2</li>
    <li title="3" class="a">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```